# Fuzzy search Optimization in SQL Server

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to optimize the performance of a stored procedure. I have to search two columns with **LIKE** operator. 
    Here is the lookup table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PrincipalDiagnosis](
        [PrincipalDiagnosisID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        [Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [PrincipalDiagnosisDescription] [varchar](3500) NULL,
   )
```

I have created two independent **NONCLUSTERED** indexes on **[Code]** and **[PrincipalDiagnosisDescription]** columns. Here is the Query of the stored procedure:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Item)) AS SearchItem
    INTO #SearchItems
    FROM dbo.SplitString(@SearchQuery, ' ')
    WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(Item))<>''

SELECT TOP (100) PrincipalDiagnosisID, 
    ISNULL(Code +' '+ PrincipalDiagnosisDescription, '') AS Info       
FROM dbo.PrincipalDiagnosis
WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM #SearchItems
            WHERE Code LIKE '%'+SearchItem+'%'
            OR PrincipalDiagnosisDescription LIKE '%'+SearchItem+'%'
         )
ORDER BY 2
```

**EXISTS** part is taking so much time. In **Execution Plan** there is table scan of #SearchItems.
I am using SQL server 2014 Enterprise edition. I want to optimize this query as much as I can. I will appreciate your valuable suggestions.
Thanks!
Muhammad

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Those two `NONCLUSTERED` Index will never be used because of leading `%` in `LIKE` operator

Comment: Yes. I can understand the disadvantage % at the start of SearchIte. But % prefix is required with SearchItem.

Comment: Consider using Full-Text Search.

Comment: Move the the temp table records to Physical table and implement `FULL TEXT SEARCH` that is the only way to optimise your query

Comment: Thanks, @Serg. I will use FullText search. Is there any other way of optimization? FullText search usually not available in SQL Server Express Editions

Comment: Thanks @Prdp . I will use FullText search. Is there any other way of optimization?

Comment: Your question says you use Enterprise Edition? It is available in Express edition anyway. You just need to download the right one with advanced services.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith. Please let me know, will FullText improve perofermance in my scenerio?

Comment: Yes. This is the point of full text indexes.

Comment: Okay. I will try FullText. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does your data look like.  FullText may not be the answer.

Comment: Data in both columns is string or text.

Comment: What @Paparazzi was probably getting at is can you give us examples of search items and text? If you need a lot of control over the items that are indexed. E.g they are not actually "words" then you might find yourself fighting against full text indexing

Comment: How are you achieving FUZZY search here? For example if your search word is 'KANNAN' and your nearest match is 'KENNAN' then you need to select that or not? If not it is not a fuzzy search it is normal search, that you can achieve numerous ways

Comment: Note the Nested Loops in the Second Query Plan.  For each record in PrincipalDiagnosisDescription it is searching to find a match in #SearchItems.  Unless you have a huge list in Search Items, you might want it to loop each items in #SearchItems for matches in PrincipalDiagnosisDescription